# Zend Custom Business Class

Tags: zend-framework

I have a membership class I want to use throughout my website. I was wondering what the easiest way would be to load it so I can access it in my Models and Controllers?

Would I need to use Zend Autoload? Also is there a convention for where to put it? Like in /application/business/membership.php?

What about third party classes?

Answer (score 0):

You would turn it into a helper class. 
This can either be a standalone class, or it could be an action helper which you would register with the Action Helper Broker.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($helper);
```

Where $helper is the instantiate class.